# Cannot vote on synonyms

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, privileges

The synonym page currently says "Users with a total answer score of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms." I have +10 in the websphere-mq tag and cannot vote. Tried in IE and Firefox with scripting enabled. No vote, no error, just a dead button. Is there a bug? Is the explanatory text wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vote for tag synonym?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92260/how-to-vote-for-tag-synonym)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 5 score (which is upvotes - down votes) (+50 points) on the tag to vote for synonyms, but you currently have 3 so far now.

[image: Screenshot showing 3 net upvotes]

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess I was confused between "score" and "points". Are these commonly interchanged in the FAQ and docs? I would think it is confusing for newbies for the docs to talk about "5 score" when it could just say "50 points" like most everything else to do with rep. Or are there subtle differences I'm not picking up on where you can't just do a simple conversion of score to points and make the docs consistent?

Comment: @mqrus, points are different on questions(+5) and answers(+10), and also downvotes could involve those calculations, so probably using "score" is more consistent than actual points?

Comment: OIC, to vote either +5-0 or +7-2 would work but do not result in the same number of points. Now I understand how it works and also understand we will never get the synonym problems fixed in the websphere-mq or any other low-volume tag. Since low-volume tags are, by definition, specialty tags, these are often where synonyms are needed most.  Pity, that.

Comment: I now have +7 in tag:websphere-mq and still cannot vote.  Not that it matters.  There are only two people eligible to vote and requests for moderator intervention got nowhere.  I guess Stack sites are really geared toward the mainstream.  Pitty, that.

Comment: @mqrus, you need 5 score for target tag to vote, not source tag, imho.