# Clarify the documentation for tag synonyms

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms, privileges, documentation

[Cannot vote on synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89564/cannot-vote-on-synonyms) has someone confused because "Users with a total answer score of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms."

Please expand (or hyperlink) what's meant by "answer score" in the tag synonym page.

(Alternatively, just drop the answer score requirement!)

Comment: we mean the total score on non wiki answers tagged `xyz`. score means total upvotes minus total downvotes. any suggestions on how we could improve the copy?

Comment: @waffles: Add  "(total upvotes minus total downvotes)" after "Users with a total answer score"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your suggestion added "(total upvotes minus total downvotes)" to the copy.

Comment: to be deployed later