# How to vote for tag synonym?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I am sure this was asked before, but I couldn't find it.

So, when I tried to vote on tag synonym, I got this :
`You do not have the required score on this tag to vote for this tag synonym`

So, what score do I need to vote for tag synonym?
What is the reason for this?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89564/cannot-vote-on-synonyms

Comment: @clairesuzy Yes, that answers what score do I need, but on which tag (the 1st or the 2nd tag?). And what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The criteria for proposing a tag synonym are as follows:

- You must have [at least 2500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).
- You must have a total answer score of 5 or more (total upvotes minus total downvotes) on the *master* tag (not the tag you're proposing as a synonym).
- If a tag has more than 50 questions in it, the proposed synonym tag cannot have a question count greater than 1.25x the master tag.
- You may not suggest any synonym that is already suggested on another tag.

The criteria for voting on a tag synonym are as follows:

- You must have a total answer score of 5 or more (total upvotes minus total downvotes) on the *master* tag (not the tag you're voting on as a synonym).

Synonyms are automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Comment: note that we relaxed some of the synonym rules for low-count tags and when the counts are "similar" between master and synonym