# When voting for a synonym tag, where can I see my total answer score for a tag?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I'd like to vote for the ["asmack"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asmack/) tag to become a synonym for the ["smack"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/smack/) tag. The rules say that I need *"... a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more..."* to vote for the synonym. Looking at [topusers for the smack tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/smack/topusers), I have a total score of 7. Isn't that the requirement for synonym voting? Or is this some other total answer score?

Because I am not able to vote, I always get "You do not have the required score on this tag to vote for this tag synonym". Where can I look-up my current score?

Comment: My two ideas would be: (a) The number is cached somewhere, and not yet known to the part of the engine which decides to let you vote or not. (b) There is a bug somewhere. Could it be that voting needs the 2500 rep too?

Comment: Paulo Ebermann: a) I have had a score >= 5 for some time. b) Maybe, I [have asked this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108635/why-cant-i-vote-for-a-tag-synonym-even-if-i-have-a-answer-score-of-5-or-higher), we will see what happens. [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92260/how-to-vote-for-tag-synonym/92271#92271) suggests that *only* a score >= is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for where to look for your score in a tag, the easiest place would be the "Tags" section way down at the bottom of your profile page, which has your total answer scores for every tag.

Your strategy of looking at topusers is likely to be much more annoying for even slightly more active tags.

Comment: Or not, because you apparently always see yourself on the top users list. Still, you can see your score for lots of tags at once on your profile.