# Why can't I vote for a tag synonym, even if I have a answer score of 5 or higher for that tag?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I'd like to vote for the ["asmack"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asmack/) tag to become a synonym for the ["smack"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/smack/) tag. The rules say that I need *"... a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more..."* to vote for the synonym. A look at [topusers for the smack tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/smack/topusers) reveals that I have a total answer score of 7, but still I am not able to vote: *You do not have the required score on this tag to vote for this tag synonym*

**Is this a bug or is the documentation unclear/wrong?**

I think that it is not a cache issue, because it is been a while since a answered a post on the tag. Also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92260/how-to-vote-for-tag-synonym/92271#92271) states that for voting only the tag's answer score counts and not the reputation. See also this quote from the tag help: **Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms.*

Comment: Curious. If you navigate to the main [tag synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) page and select the "suggested" tab, do you see the smack synonym propsal?

Comment: Yes, it is the first proposal that shows up if you select "all -> newest"

Comment: Specifically, in the suggested tab. That tab shows only the suggested synonyms you can vote on.

Comment: Yes, it is also there in the suggested tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vote code was erroneously checking reputation as well as tag score (the same check was proposals), this will be corrected in the next build.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification nick :)

Answer (score 1):

You need [a reputation of 2500](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), to propose tag synonyms and vote on proposed synonyms; your actual reputation on Stack Overflow is 474.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't like to *propose*, I'd like to *vote*

Comment: As I have written in my question, [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92260/how-to-vote-for-tag-synonym/92271#92271) just lists a score >= 5 as requirement. Also the tag wiki help states *Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms.*, which also reads like the score is the _only_ requirement.

Comment: I agree with Flow here. The suggested synonym page says: "Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms." It specifically does not state a rep requirement, when it does for suggesting a synonym. I don't know who is right, but if the vote requirement is >2.5k rep, then it's not clear at all.

Comment: @Mat It's the privilege page that reports which reputation you need to have the privilege.

Comment: Well then the suggested edit page needs fixing, IMO.

Comment: Also if > 2500 rep is also requirement for voting, then there is no difference between the requirement for suggesting and voting. Why should it then be listed explicitly?

Comment: kiamlaluno: The [first point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92260/how-to-vote-for-tag-synonym/92271#92271) is not about the required rep, it lists the criteria for *proposing*, the second one the criteria for *voting*. At least that is my understanding.

Comment: @Mat Flow is saying that he should be able to vote for synonyms when that privilege requires a higher reputation than he has.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I understand what you are saying, and what Flow is saying. I don't know which one of you is right (I suspect you are), but the wording on the suggested synonym page does not state the requirement clearly at all, IMO.

Comment: @Mat What I mean is that it is another topic (and another question). In any case, there is a page that needs to be fixed, but Flow is not objecting that.