# Where I can see my suggested tag synonyms?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

In *Activity -> Suggestion* doesn't appear and I'm wondering where are they?

Related, but doesn't answer this question:

- [Can high rep users suggest tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165345/213575)
- [When voting for a synonym tag, where can I see my total answer score for a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108607/when-voting-for-a-synonym-tag-where-can-i-see-my-total-answer-score-for-a-tag)
- [Allow moderators to see the full list of suggested synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69439/allow-moderators-to-see-the-full-list-of-suggested-synonyms) (mod's only?)

Apparently, I can use `http://SITEURL/tags/synonyms?tab=creator&filter=all` and then look my own nick... but that seems a bit overkill, is there another method?

Comment: You mean your suggestions have a chance of being approved‽ P.S., this font doesn't render interrobangs well :-(.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I'm wondering about that... that's why I need to know where they appear D:!

Comment: This should have them: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest (for SO), among other tag synonyms you can act upon, with you as the "creator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As Mat notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204083/where-i-can-see-my-suggested-tag-synonyms#comment651402_204083), they'll be in [The Giant List of All Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) (unless they've been rejected and deleted, in which case they'll be nowhere).

You can also use SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/146021/what-synonyms-have-i-suggested

Comment: Dang, a feature request question D:.

Comment: I'll make another remark: compared to the general total awesomeness of these sites, the whole tag synonym interface is, IMO, quite barbaric.

Comment: Agree that it could really use some love, @Mat. Too much to do, too few to do it. Probably worth noting that [we're hiring...](http://stackexchange.com/about/hiring)